# Handling keydown in firefox is failing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, printing

I'm trying to override the native print action of the page in my react component. 
I added these lines:

```
componentWillMount() {
 document.addEventListener('keydown', this.handlePrintKeyDown.bind(this));
}

componentWillUnmount() {
 document.removeEventListener('keydown', this.handlePrintKeyDown.bind(this));
}

handlePrintKeyDown = event => {
 //(Cntrl + P)
 if (event.ctrlKey && event.keyCode === 80) {
  document.getElementById('printme').click();
  event.preventDefault();
  return false;
 }
};
```

it works in the Chrome and Edge but in the Firefox, it still tries to open the default print. 
I have to add that what I am trying to do is to open a window and trigger print of the content of the print friendly version of my component using [react-to-print](https://github.com/gregnb/react-to-print) library.
what am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Read the following explanation on official firefox forum:

> Apparently Firefox just doesn’t care.

```
document.onkeydown = event => { console.log(event); event.preventDefault(); }
```

> stops the page save option in Chrome, but has no effect in Firefox on
>   either web or extension pages.
>
> Opening a new window probably can’t and shouldn’t be prevented (but
>   inheriting the size from the panel is stupid, as is the fact that
>   Firefox opens new tabs created with browser.tabs.create({ }) inside
>   the popup by default).

[This is the link](https://discourse.mozilla.org/t/unable-to-suppress-browser-shortcut-keys-ctrl-n-ctrl-s-from-webextension-popup/21255)